# huffman heap __init__ Exam practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, init, huffman-code

Working with huffman heaps on python 3.6 for my exam. I am doing `__init__` with the arguments (self, leafs). It should create a new heap object using a list of Huffman tree leaf nodes.

Here is what I have that should create the heap:

```
def __init__(self, leafs):
   self.leafs = leafs
   return
```

Is this the proper way to create the heap using the leafs?

Comment: Aside: plural of `leaf` is `leaves`.

Comment: Yes I know proper grammar. Im not looking for assistance in english.